# Travis give error but compiles on pc

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I'm making a web server with Node.JS and use Travis-Ci to check my code. Yhe problem I got is when I commit my code, Travis gives error below, but the code compiles without an error on my pc:

> `./backend/server.js`: 1: **Syntax error:** `(` unexpected

Here you could find my `.travis.yml` file:

```
install:
  - npm install
  - npm install -g bower
  - bower install bootstrap
  - bower install socket.io
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.9"
before_script: 
  - chmod 0777 ./backend/server.js
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - bower_components
```

and the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "watchfriends",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Front-end and back-end project watchfriends",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./backend/server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/WatchFriends/Backend.git"
  },
  "author": "Hein P., Jasper D., Michiel V., Michiel Z.",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/WatchFriends/Backend/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/WatchFriends/Backend#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.13",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-csslint": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlhint": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

On [this gist](https://gist.github.com/HeinPauwelyn/73f3d5021c54dc60220e2be1124cc2f4), you could find my code, including the log.

Did I something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you are missing `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the beginning if your script. It looks like the script is executed as shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis runs `npm test` when testing your code.

If you check inside of your "package.json" file then you can see that the `test` script is set to run `./backend/server.js`. You need to run the node file with node.

Change that to `node ./backend/server.js` and hopefully that'll work.

Comment: Oke fine it works! But how could I stop the test when it compiles without exception?

Comment: You'd have to stop the server to do that. The way you have that test setup now is kind of wrong. it's not the proper way to test the server. Have you ever heard of Mocha?

Comment: No, but I've search it on the internet. It's a bit the same of Jasmine but Mocha is for Node.JS and Jasmine for JS, or I'm I wrong? Anyway, thanks for helping me. I'll try to use that :)

Comment: Yea its similar to Jasmine, its a more modern version of it. This quick 4 minute video explains it well, its made by the Chrome devs actually. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L48AjLVgXS4